# QuickReturn library - How do you prevent blank area that displays under target view as you scroll up

Tags: android, android-listview, show-hide

I'm using [QuickReturn](https://github.com/felipecsl/QuickReturn) and upon scrolling up, there is a blank area behind the target view.

Is there a way to prevent the blank area on the target view (as you scroll up) or is this is an existing issue (I didn't see it in the issues list, but I've submitted it as a bug)?

I've tried setting the target view's height as not only 0, but other +/- values, as well. I've also tried leaving it off; e.g.:

`qrAttacher.addTargetView(testTextView, QuickReturnTargetView.POSITION_TOP, -1);`
`qrAttacher.addTargetView(testTextView, QuickReturnTargetView.POSITION_TOP, 0);`
`qrAttacher.addTargetView(testTextView, QuickReturnTargetView.POSITION_TOP, 50);`
`qrAttacher.addTargetView(testTextView, QuickReturnTargetView.POSITION_TOP);`

...but the issue persists.

Here is [a video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/501bvd6q79izalq/scroll-hide-show-test-app.mp4) demonstrating the issue.

Here is [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwLjMMIWNQU) of what it should do.

In the event there is an issue with the video, here are a series of images demonstrating what happens when scrolling up:

[image: Before scrolling]

[image: Midway scrolling]

[image: End of scrolling]

**Here is my code**:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Test Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**act_student_menu_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/studentMenuContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/studentPhotoIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_photo_grey" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/studentPhotoIcon"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/studentNameText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/studentPointsText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**onCreate in MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // The list view to show/hide on scroll.
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    TextView testTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testTextView);
    TestAdapter testAdapter = new TestAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            getListData());
    // Wrap the adapter with QuickReturnAdapter.
    listView.setAdapter(new QuickReturnAdapter(testAdapter));
    // Attach QuickReturn Attacher, which takes care of all of the hide/show functionality.
    QuickReturnAttacher qrAttacher = QuickReturnAttacher.forView(listView);
    /**
     * Add a quick return targetView to the attacher.
     * You can pass a position argument (POSITION_TOP or POSITION_BOTTOM). You can also optionally pass the size of
     * the target view, which will be used to offset the list height, preventing it from hiding content behind the
     * target view.
     */
    qrAttacher.addTargetView(testTextView, QuickReturnTargetView.POSITION_TOP, 0);
}
```

**TestAdapter.java**

```
public class TestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StudentMenuItem> {
    private final Context currentContext;
    private List<StudentMenuItem> studentMenuItems;
    ImageView studentPhotoIcon;
    TextView studentNameText;

    public TestAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<StudentMenuItem> studentMenuItems) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, studentMenuItems);
        currentContext = context;
        this.studentMenuItems = studentMenuItems;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View studentMenuOption = convertView;
        if (studentMenuOption == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) currentContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            studentMenuOption = inflater.inflate(R.layout.act_student_menu_item, parent, false);
        }
        StudentMenuItem current = studentMenuItems.get(position);
        studentNameText = (TextView) studentMenuOption.findViewById(R.id.studentNameText);
        studentNameText.setText(current.getStudentName());
        TextView studentPointsText = (TextView) studentMenuOption.findViewById(R.id.studentPointsText);
        studentPointsText.setText(current.getStudentPoints());
        studentPhotoIcon = (ImageView) studentMenuOption.findViewById(R.id.studentPhotoIcon);
        return studentMenuOption;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
}
```

**Note**: `getListData()` just returns `List<StudentMenuItem>` to populate the list.

Please help. Hopefully there is an easy fix. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Since the reply to this post was only a partial solution, I'm posting an answer with the full solution.)

In activity_main.xml:

- Move the TextView below the ListView
- Set android:layout_gravity="bottom" on the ListView
- Change the LinearLayout to a FrameLayout

Answer (score 0):

You should locate the target view (Test Title TextView) after ListView

Comment: I need the TextView at the top (as a header), so that is not a viable solution.

Comment: That's ok. move TextView after ListView and set your ListView's layout_gravity attribute to Bottom

Comment: So, I set layout_gravity to bottom and that didn't have an effect. I took another look at the developer's sample code and noticed he was using a FrameLayout. I then changed my LinearLayout to a FrameLayout and it worked. Unfortunately, we had to implement another solution due to time constraints. Thanks, anyway. Hopefully this helps someone else.